# Android: Can fingerprint sensor on an modern Android device be Class 2 (formerly weak) biometrics?

Tags: android, biometrics

As described in [this](https://source.android.com/security/biometric/measure#biometric-classes) documentation and other places online Android has different security classes for biometric sensors. It is usually considered that the fingerprint is Class 3 (formerly Strong) biometrics. But the document never explicitly says that this is always the case.
Can it be assumed that if a model (let's say Samsung A52s) has a fingerprint, therefore it has a Class 3 biometrics sensor?